# Hypothesis testing time series using permutation tests

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I am performing a permutation (exact) test on some data and would like a sound check or to be schooled if what I’m doing is statistically valid or not. I have multiple time series that might experience an event on any given day which leads to my hypothesis that on any given day the event occurs the day-to-day percentage change will have greater standard deviation than that on days where the event does not occur.

H0: σno_event ≥ σevent

HA: σno_event < σevent

To test my hypothesis I randomly sample 3000 samples of days where the event occurred and 3000 samples where the event did not occur (recording the percentage change). I then run a permutation test where I run 10000 iterations where samples are combined, shuffled and then put into two random n=3000 samples. The standard deviation is calculated for both and the difference in stdv is calculated, if this test statistic is greater than the observed difference (stdv of event - stdv of no event) then I increment a counter.  At the end of the test I calculate the p value as being the # of times the test statistic is greater than the observed difference / 10000. If the p value is greater than my alpha value I reject the null hypothesis and conclude that there is a significant difference between the stdvs.

Comment: It's not clear what the day-to-day percentage change is, and how you compute the standard deviation. Day-to-day implies you compute a statistic by comparing two consecutive days. So it's not immediately obvious how does fit in with whether an event occurs on any given day or not. Also, how come you have 3000 samples (days?) with and without an event? 3000 days is more than 8 years.

Comment: I'm calculating day to day percentage change by (todays value - yesterdays value) / yesterdays value. So if the event happened today the day to day percentage (increase or decrease) would be a larger % than 'typical' day to day changes. The samples are being randomly taken from multiple different time series that all experience the same events.

Comment: I don't understand this proposal. If you observe the same event simultaneously across multiple time series, isn't it more straightforward to start there: detect (a signature/a pattern) that a change is happening at the same time?

Comment: @dipetkov there are multiple events that are known and recorded on the days they occur, and differ slightly in observed effect. The proposal is to confirm analysis by means of a permutation test on the test statistic of interest (stdv of day-to-day percentage change), to confirm that's what's seen in analysis is statistically significant. Does that help? Would sampling in the way I've outline be valid for this kind of test?

Comment: You need to mimic the actual data in your permuting. So if you have 67 event days and 2645 non event days, then use those numbers to calculate your test statistic in every permutation sample.